# RPM Installation dependency error

Tags: linux, package, rpm, rhel6

I am attempting to install StackStorm on a RHEL6 environment since I was encountering issues with their deployment script. I believe I got all the required software installed but have been encountering issues trying to install the actual StackStorm packages. All my commands are run with the sudo prefix as the root user.

Ex command:

```
sudo rpm -i st2common-0.11.0-6.noarch.rpm
```

Output:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by st2common-0.11.0-6.noarch
```

Here is the resource I am using:
http://docs.stackstorm.com/install/rpm.html

How can I resolve this dependency error and update python?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of python do you have running on your machine?

Comment: CentOS 6 ships with python 2.6. I believe there may be an SCL for python 2.7 but I'm not sure offhand. If that package actually requires python 2.7 then they built it on a non-stock CentOS 6 machine and you should probably ask them what their **actual** dependencies are. Also that page and the version you are trying to install don't match versions. You are using `0.11.0` and those docs are for `0.12.0`.

Comment: Ah and I just noticed the "StackStorm RPMs have been tested and precompiled for Fedora 20." line at the top.

Comment: The machine's default python is 2.6. I have installed 2.7 and attempted to symlink to 2.7, but either it didn't work or I didn't do it correctly.

Comment: Good catch Etan, didn't realize that I wasn't attempting installing the correct packages. Though, I just tried it with the packages from 0.12.0 and still have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using yum.

```
    yum localinstall st2common-0.11.0-6.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: `yum` isn't going to install python2.7 on a CentOS 6 box.